# email hyperlink in MailMessage

Tags: asp.net, email, .net-4.0

I'm using the following as part of sending a .net 4 email. I'd like to show the reply to text as an email hyperlink but can't quite get the format correct.

```
nMail.Body = Description " + txtdescription.Text +
             "<br />Reply to (click here):" + txtemail.Text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following if the e-mail address is contained in txtemail.Text.  Remember to first validate the content of txtemail.Text.  The output of the following is a hyperlink to an e-mail address that also contains the e-mail address as the hyperlink text.

```
nMail.Body = "Description " + txtdescription.Text + "<br />Reply to (click here): " + "<a href='mailto:" + txtemail.Text + "'>" + txtemail.Text + "</a>");
```

Comment: You mean because it could contain markup? But, like I said, he needs to validate it to confirm it is a valid e-mail address.

Comment: You can put an XSS attack in a valid (but unusual) email address.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the address in an anchor tag `<a>` to make a link. Also make sure you encode the input.
Use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` on text and `Uri.EscapeUriString` on links.

```
nMail.Body = "Description " +
             HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtdescription.Text) +
             "<br />Reply to <a href=\"mailto:" +
             Uri.EscapeUriString(txtemail.Text) +
             "\">" +
             HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtemail.Text) +
             "</a>");
```

Comment: @SLaks - I'm not sure I follow. `<a href='mailto:'></a>` is already valid HTML.

Comment: What if the email address is `">Evil HTML"@evil.org`?  That's a valid address.

Comment: @SLaks - `Uri.EscapeDataString` and `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` safely encode it. However single quotes aren't escaped, so I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I hadn't realized that `EscapeUriString` escapes HTML characters too.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `<a href='mailto:username@example.com'>Link Text</a>`.

Comment: what if I need to pick te address from a field on a form though?

Comment: Then you can concatenate the string.  (And remember to encode the HTML)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    private string BuildEmailText(string description, string replyToAddress, string replyToText)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} <a href='{1}'>{2}</a>", description, replyToAddress, replyToText);
    }
```